# Hash syntax in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax-error

According to *The Well Grounded Rubyist*:

Ruby allows a special form of symbol representation in the hash-key position, with the colon after the symbol instead of before it and the hash separator arrow removed. In other words, this:

```
hash = { :name => "David", :age => 49 }
```

can also be written like this:

```
hash = { name: David, age: 49 }
```

I have tried the preceding code in ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 - It is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the future, please post detailed error messages if you can't make a code snippet work. This is much more useful than "it's not working".

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to know when the `hash`s `json-like` syntax to be used, and it is apparently available only with `symbols`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The new hash syntax in Ruby 1.9 still requires that strings be quoted, so instead of `David` you need `"David"`.

Try this:

```
hash = { name: "David", age: 49 }
```

If the book used the bare word `David` without quotation marks, it is wrong. You might be interested in reading some of the [other errata](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/forum.jspa?forumID=417).

Comment: Specifically this one: http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=33960&tstart=0

Comment: Does Ruby treat name: as a symbol, i.e. :name?

Comment: @loungerdork Yes. It's exactly equivalent to `{ :name => "David" }`